# What does ssh-keygen's -a option really mean?

Tags: password-cracking, bcrypt, openssh

I discovered the newer [OpenSSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSSH) format for storing SSH private keys (`ssh-keygen -o`) uses [bcrypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/bcrypt) to generate the [symmetric key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric-key_algorithm) to encrypt the private key. I understand that the `-a` option is used to adjust the bcrypt work factor. However, I don't understand the exact relationship between the work factor and the given value. `-a 200` takes about 5 seconds on my CPU, while [this benchmark](https://wildlyinaccurate.com/bcrypt-choosing-a-work-factor/) maxes out with a work factor of 20 taking over a minute. The work factor is a logarithmic scale, and I doubt my laptop is really >2^10 times faster than this person's laptop.

Clearly `-a` does not directly translate to the bcrypt work factor. So what **is** the relationship?

The reason I want to know is to extrapolate a "worst-case" cracking rate for my chosen `-a` value based on [this benchmark](https://gist.github.com/epixoip/a83d38f412b4737e99bbef804a270c40) of a top-end (for 2017) cracking rig (which guesses ~100k hashes/sec across 8 GPUs, using a bcrypt work factor of 5 for the tests).

Comment: First, I notice typical ssh-keygen use single core.   seconds, please edit your question and provide the exact command line and crypto bits. 
When trying `ssh-keygen -a 200` , my i7 3600  2.2Ghz CPU show "Sieve next 67043328 plus 2047-bit", "Sieved with 203277289 small primes in 184 seconds"

Comment: there is no single exact command line; this is talking about a whole range of uses of `ssh-keygen`. The relevant options are `-o` to specify using the OpenSSH format instead of the older PEM format, and `-a <number>` to specify work factor. Here is an example to generate a test key though: `ssh-keygen -o -a 200 -f ./testkey -N password123`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This differs between `ssh-keygen` versions. From [this post](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/40910/8791):

> The original difficulty parameter for bcrypt is the log2 number of
>   times to rekey the cipher. bhash fixes this number at 64, and instead
>   relies on the PBKDF2 rounds parameter to control difficulty.

My original answer was based on the man page for `ssh-keygen` which states the following:

> -a rounds
>                     When saving a new-format private key (i.e. an ed25519 key or any SSH protocol 2 key when the -o flag is set), this option
>   specifies the number of KDF (key derivation function) rounds used.
>                    Higher numbers result in slower passphrase verification and increased resistance to brute-force password cracking
>   (should the keys be stolen).

Therefore a value of 200 will iterate the KDF 200 times. This is an equivalent of [a work factor of 7.64](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=log2(200)), not 200 as you are expecting.

If you wanted your workfactor of 200 you would have to specify [`-a 
1606938044258990275541962092341162602522202993782792835301376`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E200).

This won't work for two reasons:

- `Invalid number (too large)` is returned.
- You don't have a few universes of time to spare.

If you wanted to try 20 like in the example, go with [this number](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%5E20), 1048576.

Basically you need the following two formulae:

> Work factor = log2(rounds)
>
> Rounds = 2<sup>work factor</sup>

## Update

Therefore, if using the bhash version, divide the number from my working above by 64.

```
$ time ssh-keygen -o -a 16384 -f ./testkey -N password123
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in ./testkey.
Your public key has been saved in ./testkey.pub.
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:eU/T6ex/wDJNsb8soOzGN/uxup0Zdjthvxt1e23wb6c foo@bar
The key's randomart image is:
+---[RSA 2048]----+
|                 |
|              .  |
|               o |
|         .   .o. |
|        S . o++.o|
|         . +o++=*|
|        o . o*==O|
|         = oooB=X|
|        o..+**EBO|
+----[SHA256]-----+

real    2m17.181s
user    2m16.677s
sys 0m0.005s
```

Comment: Thank you! I was starting to suspect this as I experimented, somehow I didn't think to actually take the man page at its word.

Comment: In a situation like this where this is well said and clearly the right answer, should I accept right away, or should I still give other people a chance first?

Comment: Your call on how to run it. Completely up to you. ;-)

Comment: whoops, turns out this is not exactly correct after all, as per this answer: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/40910/49054

Comment: Yes I wondered if the format specified changed the behaviour. It is still correct, just that the internal function does multiple iterations per the count specified. I can update my answer later.

Comment: update looks good, thanks! I wonder what motivated them to do bcrypt wrapped in PBKDF2, seems like an unusual choice.